# AUCTeX is obsolete on GNU ELPA?

Tags: auctex, package, package-repositories, install

I got this warning when installing AUCTeX from GNU ELPA. The package is installed, but I don't want to use obsolete packages for obvious reasons. I have check the [official website](https://www.gnu.org/software/auctex/index.html) of AUCTeX, and it says current version is 12.1 (2017-12-10).

[image]

If this package is obsolete, which one is its replacement?

Comment: AUCTeX is not obsolete, and 12.1.2 is indeed its latest version. My guess is you are witnessing a variant of [bug#34390](https://debbugs.gnu.org/34390) in `package.el`, the package manager.

Comment: As Basil says, it looks like a bug.  I seems different from the bug#34390, so I think you should create a new bug report with `M-x report-emacs-bug`.

Comment: Same here, same version of emacs. Did you get an answer ?

Comment: @jcm69 I’m afraid not, but the comments above seem reasonable to me, so I just ignored it.